# PHP. Imagecolorallocate returns false

Tags: php, image, gd

I use some code:

```
$colors = array ();
$colors['test'] = imagecolorallocate($img, 0 ,1 ,2);
....
```

It works until I change picture to other
After that `imagecolorallocate` and `imagecolorallocatealpha` return `false`
`$img` is correct image, i.e  `imagepng` print it correctly

How to make `imagecolorallocate` work?

Comment: Are you checking for `false` with the identity operator (`===`)?

Comment: I use var_dump($colors);die();

Comment: What kind of image is it that fails `imagecolorallocate`? An 8 bit image?

Comment: Also, what does "works until I change picture to other" mean?

Comment: I don't know anything about images. [This is incorrect image image](http://hyippatrol.com/images/informer.png)

Comment: Works with [this image](http://hyippatrol.com/images/monitorbutton.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment on the documentation of this function:

> If you even in a situation where it's
> not allocating the color you want it
> could be because of your images color
> allocation table. GIF and 8-bit PNG
> images are very susceptible to this.
>
> If your using an GIF and PNG try
> dropping a color from the table,
> should let you allocate another.

If the source image in an indexed image (8-bit or less) then make sure there is room for additional colors. E.g. an 8-bit image might not be using all 256 colors from the palette in that case the function should succeed and it will not otherwise.

## Edit

I looked at your image and it is infact an 8-bit PNG image that uses all 256 colors. Try converting it to a true color image (either via photoshop or by copying the image into a GD image created via `imagecreatetruecolor()`); do all the editing, then save as GIF.

Comment: Thank, Will try to do it now.